# How to detect 30 seconds duration

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer, nstimeinterval

I have a case study here. In which I have a function named

```
loadData(action:String)
```

on viewDidLoad I am calling this function as loadData("sync") Now I want to recall this function as loadData("load")  if its calling interval is inbetween 30 seconds. Lets say I want to call this function with "sync" if 30 seconds have been passed and if not then "load"

Please guide me.

Comment: Could you please explain more :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is one solution to use `NSTimer` to count the seconds. and when you first call the `loadData("sync")` method start the timer. and increment the second. and when you have to recall this function check the calculated seconds if it is > 30 then call `sync` otherwise call `load`. see the below code.

```
var timer : NSTimer!
var second = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // here you start your first sync method.

    loadData("sync")

    // start the timer here so you can get how many seconds before you started or called your method.
    timer = NSTimer()
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.calculateSeconds), userInfo: nil, repeats: true) 
}

func calculateSeconds() {
     second += 1
}
```

now when you have to recall the `loadData` method check the second variable that if it is > 30 then call `sync` else `load`. and `invalidate` that timer to that the timer will stop monitoring or calculating the second.

Like this.

```
func whatever() {
     if second > 30 {
         loadData("sync") 
     } else {
         loadData("load")
     }

     second = 0
     timer.invalidate()
     timer = nil
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you call your function with the parameter "sync", then put one of the two options (depending on your version of Swift - have you downloaded the developer beta - if not then use Swift 2 option) below in to call loadData with the parameter "load" after 30 seconds.
If you're using the Swift 3 Option, replace className with whatever class your function is in - most likely it's ViewController or the name of your UIViewController.

**Swift 3**

```
var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 30.0, target: self, selector: #selector(className.loadData(action:)), userInfo: "load", repeats: false)
```

**Swift 2**

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(30.0, target: self, selector: "loadDataLater:", userInfo: "load", repeats: false)
//Then you have to define a new function as below
func loadDataLater(inputTimer: NSTimer) {
     var action = inputTimer.userInfo as String
     //The body of the loadData function goes here
}
```

Please feel free to let me know if you have any further questions or issues :)

Answer (score 1):

create a instance variable `var lastSync = NSDate()`

set the current date to `lastSync` when you use the sync action

```
func loadData(action:String)
{
    if action == "sync" 
    {
      lastSync = NSDate()
    }

}
```

while calling your `loadData:` check for time interval

```
let timeInsterval = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(lastSync)
let reqAction = timeInsterval > 30 ? "sync" : "load"
```

then call your method by passing `reqAction` as parameter

```
loadData(reqAction)
```